# Missing period in explanation about review queue badges

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, wording, help-text

When mousing over the badge progress in a review queue, one gets the following explanation:

> These badges are awarded once per review queue

which is missing a period. Can someone fix this admittedly trivial problem?

[image: screenshot]

Look at the bottom line of text.

Comment: Well, I guess that's an appropriate bug report from someone with obsessive in their username ;P

Comment: It does miss a ".", good eyes you got young man.

Comment: @YannisRizos Just pass me a list of all of the SE UI text and I'll scour it carefully... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the retag done by Geoff Dalgas ♦, this has been fixed.

Just trying to get this out of the unanswered section...